# Java Money get exchange rate hanging

Tags: java, java-8, java-money

I was trying simple money conversion in using java money-api & moneta repository.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.money</groupId>
    <artifactId>money-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.javamoney</groupId>
    <artifactId>moneta</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2</version>
</dependency>
```

```
IMFHistoricRateProvider imf = new IMFHistoricRateProvider();

LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
ExchangeRate exr = null;
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("2021-05-25", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
exr = imf.getExchangeRate(ConversionQueryBuilder.of().setBaseCurrency("EUR").setTermCurrency("USD").set(LocalDate.class, date).build());
System.out.println(exr.getFactor() + " ==" + (System.currentTimeMillis()-start));
```

Here exr.getFactor() method gives the exchange rate for the given date, but its getting hanged at a state for hours.

PF log at which its hanging.

```
May 27, 2021 4:59:26 PM org.javamoney.moneta.spi.loader.LoadDataLoaderService execute
INFO: Read data from: [https://www.imf.org/external/np/fin/data/rms_five.aspx?tsvflag=Y]
May 27, 2021 4:59:26 PM org.javamoney.moneta.convert.imf.IMFAbstractRateProvider newDataLoaded
INFO: Loaded IMFHistoricRateProvider exchange rates for days:50
May 27, 2021 4:59:26 PM org.javamoney.moneta.spi.loader.LoadDataLoaderService execute
INFO: New data successfully loaded from: [https://www.imf.org/external/np/fin/data/rms_five.aspx?tsvflag=Y]
```

It should give exchange rate from EUR to USD for the X local date from past.

Reference : https://dzone.com/articles/looking-java-9-money-and  (Exchange rates)

Answer (score 0):

I have change the dependence from moneta to more specific exchange rate provider moneta-convert-ecb

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.money</groupId>
    <artifactId>money-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.javamoney.moneta</groupId>
    <artifactId>moneta-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.javamoney.moneta</groupId>
    <artifactId>moneta-convert-ecb</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Also changed

```
IMFHistoricRateProvider imf = new IMFHistoricRateProvider();
```

to

```
ExchangeRateProvider ecb = new ECBHistoricRateProvider();
```

All though this fix worked but it is just changing of provider from IMF to ECB.

Note : IMF was still behaving same.